# Regexp to match words two by two (or n by n)

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, text, nlp

I'm looking for a regexp which is able to match words n by n. Let's say `n := 2`, it would yield:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit`

`Lorem ipsum`, `ipsum dolor`, `dolor sit`, `sit amet` (notice the comma here), `consectetur adipiscing`, `adipiscing elit`.

I have tried using `\b` for word boundaries to no avail. I am really lost trying to find a regex capable of giving me `n` words... `/\b(\w+)\b(\w+)\b/i` can't cut it, and even tried multiple combinations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: @Biffen how is it a duplicate of that question?

Comment: This is basically a *give-me-a-regex* ‘question’. They're all duplicates (in a way) of that one.

Comment: @Biffen, even though I really like your philosophy, I am really lost trying to find a regex capable of giving me n words... `/\b(\w+)\b(\w+)\b/i` can't cut it, and even tried multiple combinations.

Comment: You need overlapping matches and `\W+` between words. Check  https://jsfiddle.net/ncxucvfk/

Comment: @JoColina I don't think you've quite grasped how `\b` works: `(\w+)\b(\w+)` can't ever match anything, since there is never, by definition, a word boundary (`\b`) between to word characters (`\w`). You're going to have to take non-word characters like whitespace and punctuation into account.

Comment: @Biffen ok, see it now, \W+ is the trick, however @Wiktor, I'm getting `amet, consectetur`. Gonna pop them from the array though! Thanks a lot

Comment: I did not pay attention: so, the only words you need are separated with whitespace? Then, you need `\s+`, not `\W+` between.

Comment: I'm puzzled by why you seem to think regexp is relevant here, other than possibly to break the sentence into words. Once you have words, it's a simple affair to create the "n-grams" (which is what your n-word groups are called).

Comment: @Biffen No, it's a *give-me-a-regexp-even-though-that's-not-what-I-really-need* question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are not really what you need here, other than to split the input into words. The problem is that this problem involves matching **overlapping** substrings, which regexp is not very good at, especially the JavaScript flavor. Instead, simply break the input into words, and a quick piece of JavaScript will generate the "n-grams" (which is the correct term for your n-word groups).

```js
const input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit";

// From an array of words, generate n-grams.
function ngrams(words, n) {
  const results = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < words.length - n + 1; i++) 
    results.push(words.slice(i, i + n));

  return results;
}

console.log(ngrams(input.match(/\w+./g), 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

A word boundary `\b` does not *consume* any characters, it is a zero-width assertion, and only *asserts* the position between a word and non-word chars, and between start of string and a word char and between a word char and  end of string.

You need to use `\s+` to *consume* whitespaces between words, and use capturing inside a positive lookahead technique to get overlapping matches:

```js
var n = 2;
var s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit";
var re = new RegExp("(?=(\\b\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+){" + (n-1) + "}\\b))", "g");
var res = [], m;
while ((m=re.exec(s)) !== null) { // Iterating through matches
 if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {  // This is necessary to avoid 
        re.lastIndex++;           // infinite loops with 
 }                                // zero-width matches
 res.push(m[1]);                  // Collecting the results (group 1 values)
}
console.log(res);
```

The final pattern will be built dynamically since you need to pass a variable to the regex, thus you need a `RegExp` constructor notation. It will look like

```
/(?=(\b\w+(?:\s+\w+){1}\b))/g
```

And it will find  all locations in the string that are followed with the following sequence:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `(?:\s+\w+){n}` - `n` sequences of:

  - `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary

Comment: This seems like massive overkill.

Comment: A working, expandable solution is never an overkill.

Answer (score -1):

Not a pure regex solution, but it works and is easy to read and understand:

```
let input = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';
let matches = input.match(/(\w+,? \w+)/g)
    .map(str => str.replace(',', ''));

console.log(matches) // ['Lorem ipsum', 'dolor sit', 'amet consectetur', 'adipiscing elit']
```

Warning: Does not check for no matches (`match()` returns null)